# Keras - Pattern prediction using LSTM

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

For my experiment, I have a formatted [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vO62n7GolfvCOHLkPEmc1VLwrV6iPc5n) with three columns (time_stamp, X and Y - where Y is the actual value). I wanted to predict the value of X from Y based on time index from past values. As you can see it in the following plot, the pattern prediction using machine learning regression seems to work very well.

[image]

I want to reproduce this prediction (plot) using deep learning techniques (for example using [LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)) and here is how I approached the problem with [Keras](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.0.4/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(7)

df = pd.read_csv('test32_C_data.csv')
n_features=10

values = df.values

for i in range(0,n_features):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i) 
    df['X_tp'+str(i)] = (df['X'].shift(i) - df['X'].shift(i+1))/(df['X'].shift(i))

print(df)
pd.set_option('use_inf_as_null', True)

#df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(axis=1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)

X_train = X_train.drop('time', axis=1)
X_train = X_train.drop('X_t1', axis=1)
X_train = X_train.drop('X_t2', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('time', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('X_t1', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('X_t2', axis=1)


sc = MinMaxScaler()

X_train = np.array(df['X'])
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)

y_train = np.array(df['Y'])
y_train=y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = sc.fit_transform(y_train)


model_data = TimeseriesGenerator(X_train, y_train, 100, batch_size = 10) 

# Initialising the RNN
model = Sequential() 

# Adding the input layerand the LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(None, 1)))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(1)) 

# Compiling the RNN
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop') 

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
model.fit_generator(model_data)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
#print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# Getting the predicted values
predicted = X_test
predicted = np.reshape(-1, 1)
predicted = sc.transform(predicted)
y_pred = model.predict(predicted)
y_pred = sc.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

However, when I try to run the prediction model (`y_pred = model.predict(predicted)`) as shown above - I am getting the following error.

`ValueError: Error when checking: expected lstm_2_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)`

What am I doing wrong in here? I would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM input has rank 3:

- The **batch size**: in your case it's **`1`**, but any value will work.
- The **time steps**: the model accepts any value, so **`1`** will do it, but longer input sequence usually leads to better predictions.
- The **features**: indicated to be **`1`** in the model.

So you should reshape the `predicted` to:

```
predicted = predicted.values.reshape((-1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: I see, it's all coming from pandas dataframe. Add `.values` to convert it to numpy array. To fix the scaler, you should convert the training set to rank 3 as well.

Comment: it seems to work without error if I change the order like this `predicted = sc.transform(predicted)
predicted = predicted.reshape((-1, 1, 1))` though I am not sure if that will affect the performance :-)

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos yes, this works too. It doesn't matter if the array is reshaped before or after scaling